# Linux semaphore_init: error implicit declaration of function 'semaphore_init'

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I recently updated Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04 this changed the linux Kernel from 2.6.35-30-server to 3.0.0-29-server. After the update I am currently getting an error when I am compiling my driver code.

> error: implicit declaration of function 'semaphore_init' [-Werror=implict-function-declaration].

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `semaphore_init` is a function of your own making, I think you'll want `sema_init` instead.

Comment: This is indeed the answer. I don't know why it would work under 2.6.*, but it doesn't work [under 3.0.*](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/semaphore.h;h=dc368b8ce215ccc0f6a2b44a16dd2aaa603dbcd1;hb=HEAD). Instead of `semaphore_init(x)`, use `sema_init(x,1)`.